# Alternative to using onfocus on a div to change border

Tags: javascript, html, css, onfocus

When the user clicks on one of these divs I want it to do 2 things:

1. Show the contents of the div in the div #bigScreen
2. Highlight the tiny div they clicked on with a border. Once they click on something else I want the border to revert back to its original state.

Got it to turn the border on but cant turn it off. See example below.

```
<div id="2" class="previewPanelEntry" onclick="showIt(this.id)">2</div>

<script>
function showIt(id){
  /*-- onclick find all items highlighted and unhighlight them so there is only one selected --*/
  var highlighted = document.getElementsByClassName('highlighted');
  for (var d in highlighted) {
    /*-- THIS IS WHAT DOESNT WORK --*/
    d.className = "previewPanelEntry";
  }

  /*-- put contents of most recently selected div on the big screen --*/
  bigScreen.innerHTML = selection[id];

  /*-- highlight the most recently selected div --*/
  document.getElementById(id).className ="highlighted";

}
</script>
```

Heres a more complete version but jsfiddle wont run it right because javascript needs to load after the html. Not sure how to specify this in jfiddle.

http://jsfiddle.net/94zk7/2/

Comment: If you want the user to click on the `div`, why are you not using `onclick`?

Comment: I am. Just edited my original post. See the div in my first line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've [updated your jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/94zk7/6/) so that it works the way you indicate you want, here's the code:

```
window.onload=function(){
    var previewPanel = document.getElementById('previewPanel');
    var selection = ["a", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12", "13", "14", "15", "16", "z"];
    for (var c in selection) {
        var newPreviewPanelEntry = document.createElement('div');
        newPreviewPanelEntry.id = c;
        newPreviewPanelEntry.className = "previewPanelEntry";
        newPreviewPanelEntry.addEventListener('click',showIt);
        newPreviewPanelEntry.innerHTML = "selection[" + c + "]";
        previewPanel.appendChild(newPreviewPanelEntry);
    }
    var newClear = document.createElement('div');
    newClear.className = "clear";
    previewPanel.appendChild(newClear);

    function showIt(event) {
        var siblings = event.target.parentNode.children;
        for (var i=0; i<siblings.length; i++) {
            siblings[i].style.border = "";
        }
        event.target.style.border = "1px solid red";
        var bigScreen = document.getElementById('bigScreen');
        bigScreen.innerHTML = event.target.innerHTML;
    }
}
```

Some things to note:

- The jsFiddle wraps everything into a function which is called in the `load` event of the `window`, this is what that first line is.  This has some consequences, one of which is..
- None of your functions are global, they exist within the closure scope of the `load` event only, which means...
- You need to attach the event handlers in DOM rather than by adding `onclick` attributes, but, actually, you should be doing it that way anyway.  I've used `addEventListener` for this, note that this [won't work in older IE](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_advanced.html), you could also attach like `newPreviewPanelEntry.onclick = showIt` but this only allows for a single event listener per node.
- You hadn't created any of your global variables like `previewPanel` and `bigScreen`, so I added in code for that.
- There's no real need to add an `onclick` listener to every element in your array, just add the listener to `previewPanel`, the event will bubble up.  You can [see this working here](http://jsfiddle.net/94zk7/7/).  The main trick with this approach is to make sure you're handling the event for the element you're interested in.  For example, if you add further child elements to your clickable nodes, each of those child elements can trigger the click event.  In this case, in addition to the check I used, you should probably check that the `event.target` has an `id` defined.
- I created a version which [implemented your next and previous links](http://jsfiddle.net/94zk7/8/), again the main trick is to add the handlers within the `onload` closure rather than as attrubutes.

Comment: Wow thank you. You answered my question, my extra credit jsfiddle question, and one I didnt ask. Wish I could give you 3 check marks.

Answer (score 0):

If you create an anchor link around an object it should be focusable/tab-able...

example:

```
<p>I can't tab to this text</p>
<p><a href=#>But I can tab to this text</a></p>
```

I haven't done HTML in a while but still, try it with a DIV, if not you can do it with something else like a SPAN and then edit the CSS properties to make it act like a DIV (i.e. `display: block;`).

Some other events you might be interested in:
OnMouseOver (mouse hovers over object)
OnMouseOut (mouse leaves object)
OnClick (click once)
OnMouseDown (half click)
OnMouseUp (release click)
OnFocus you already know
OnBlur (the anti-focus)

If you want to switch a DIV between two styles, it may be easier for you to do it with CSS, and only change the class field of the object.

example:

```
//style
...
.div-off {
   border: 1px solid black; 
}
.div-on {
   border: 1px solid #BBDDFF;
   background-color: #CCCCFF;
}
...
//script
...
divList = new Array() {"div1","div2","div3"};
function switchStyle(obj) {
    for (i=0; i<divList.length; i++)
        document.getElementById(divList[i]).className = "div-off";
    obj.className = "div-on";
}
...
//html
<div id="div1" class="div-off" onClick=switchStyle(this);>div1</div>
<div id="div2" class="div-off" onClick=switchStyle(this);>div2</div>
<div id="div3" class="div-off" onClick=switchStyle(this);>div3</div>
```